# Check if plugin is being disabled

Tags: plugins

I have created a wordpress plugin.
But when i disable the plugin i must delete a certain file before a user can reactivate the plugin.
Is there a function or a way to know when someone disables my plugin

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there are activation and deactivation hooks. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/

```
<?php
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_deactivate_myplugin' );

function wpse_deactivate_myplugin() {
// Delete the file and do any other cleanup needed here.
}
```

Comment: What if the plugin gets deactivated due to an error, or the plugin folder is removed forcefully via (S)FTP?